# Class not loading

Tags: 8, symfony-services

For my module cloudinary_storage_db I have a cloudinary_storage_db.services.yml with the following:

```
services:
  cloudinary_storage_db:
    class: Drupal\cloudinary_storage_db\CloudinaryStorageDb
```

There is a matching CloudinaryStorageDb.php file in my module's src directory.  Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to load, and class_exists('CloudinaryStorageDb') returns false.  What am I missing here?  I've tried clearing caches multiple times to no avail.  How can I force it to load the file?  Do I have to do an include - thought the autoloading eliminated that?

The class file contains this:

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\cloudinary_storage_db;

use Drupal\cloudinary_storage\CloudinaryStorage;

/**
 * Implements cloudinary storage with database.
 */
class CloudinaryStorageDb extends CloudinaryStorage {
...
```

Comment: Are you injecting this service anywhere or calling it with the global Drupal service container?

Comment: `class_exists('CloudinaryStorageDb')` won't find a class because the parameter is not using the full namespace. You would need to try `class_exists('\Drupal\cloudinary_storage_db\CloudinaryStorageDb')`

Comment: Also, see: https://www.drupal.org/node/2133171